# How to improve serialization speed on wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf, compression, entity, netnamedpipebinding

Again a question about compression on wcf services.
I'm using netnamedpipe binding to send some entity objects to my calling application.
I know, that's a bad idea, but that's the way my customer wants it to be implemented.

So right now, I have to send about 45000 datasets (entity objects) via netnamedpipe.
That's really really slow. I've implemented a class which compresses the data objects to
byte[] before sending, but 45000 sets are still taking 'bout 45 seconds to send/receive.

I'm compressing like this:

```
public static byte[] Compress<T>(T data)
{
    byte[] result = null;
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new DeflateStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(zip, data);
        }
        result = memory.ToArray();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to improve that? 45 seconds are too much :( I think, main reason could be serialization of my entity objects.. but how to speed that up?

Comment: "how to improve serialization speed on wcf service?" - send less...

Comment: How big are your objects?  45,000 objects is quite a bit...

Comment: Look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/07/10/comparing-the-performance-of-net-serializers.aspx

Comment: Also why are you doing explicit conversion to `byte[]`? WCF is already pretty good at doing binary serialization...

Comment: Why do you think it is the serialization that is taking all of the time? Have you profiled the various parts of the sending application, and determined that most of the time is spent serializing the objects? If so, how much of the time (as a %) is it? If not, I'd suggest starting by doing that. You can't fix what you can't measure.

Comment: send less is not possible at all.

Comment: sending less is not possible, because customer wants it like that. i've moved to poco objects now and it's working fine in about 1-2 seconds. thanks for ur help, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using DTO pattern. Send only those fields which are required

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using byte[] it seems you have full control - in which case I would recommend trying protobuf-net as the serializer. This uses considerably less CPU, and usually considerably less bandwidth too.

If you dta is dominated by strings (paragraphs of text in descriptions etc) then you could also add some GZipStream/DeflateStream into the mix (as you already show), to chip off a few more bytes bandwidth.

Switching to protobuf-net from a POCO is usually pretty easy.

---

If by data set you mean DataSet/DataTable, then enabling the internal binary serialization will help (it uses XML by default, even via BinaryFormatter). If so, change the RemotingFormat property to binary.